# Pushing in an array if the condition is true

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, foreach, push

I have the following chart:

```
const array = [
  ["one", true],
  ["two", false],
  ["three", false],
  ["four", true]
]
```

I would like to see this variable added when the value is true:

```
const add = ["ok"]
```

So that in the end it looks like this:

```
[
  [ 'one', true, 'ok' ],
  [ 'two', false ],
  [ 'three', false ],
  [ 'four', true, 'ok' ],
]
```

Currently, I'm trying the .map method:

```
const testBoolean = array.map(el => {
  if (el[1] === true){
    array.push(add)
  }
})

console.log(array)
```

But I don't know where to tell it to push to line 3...

Thanks for your help, and have a nice day :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use map if you mean forEach. Only use map if you need the resulting array - in this case testBoolean would be a map

You want this

```js
const array = [
  ["one", true],
  ["two", false],
  ["three", false],
  ["four", true]
]
const add = ["ok"]

array.forEach(el => {
  if (el[1] === true) {  // or just if (el[1]) if you are sure it is always a boolean
    el.push(...add) // or add[0]
  }
})

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

simply loop through array using `forEach` and check if the first index is true.
For boolean values you don't need to compare it with true or false.

```js
const array = [
  ["one", true],
  ["two", false],
  ["three", false],
  ["four", true]
];

const add = ["ok"]

array.forEach(item => {
    if(item[1]){
    item.push(...add);
  }
});

console.log(array)
```

documentation for [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```js
const array = [
  ["one", true],
  ["two", false],
  ["three", false],
  ["four", true]
];

const add = ["ok"];


for (const item of array) {
  item[1] && item.push(add[0]);
}
```